# INSERT INTO with WHERE IN clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, insert

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ASTMListCustom ([ASTMID], [EDMID], [Distance], [Selected])
    SELECT 
        ASTMID, 'HWG - VT', 1, 1
    FROM   
        dbo.ASTMListCustom
    WHERE 
        ASTMID IN ( 15, 21, 22, 23, 25, 38, 63, 72, 73, 74, 75, 82, 83, 125, 130, 163, 165, 182, 206, 207, 208, 214, 217, 250, 255, 256, 257, 264, 266, 299, 317, 342, 348, 349, 350, 357, 381, 382, 391, 392, 397, 398, 422, 448, 450, 451, 466, 481, 9, 12, 17, 18, 26, 61, 62, 67, 68, 69, 70, 77, 85, 92, 93, 94, 95, 126, 128, 129, 136, 137, 145, 146, 153, 154, 179, 203, 211, 213, 219, 221, 237, 253, 254, 261, 262, 301, 326, 327, 328, 329, 343, 346, 353, 368, 369, 386, 394, 436)
```

I'm trying to insert one row for each `ASTMID` but it ends up duplicating the number of rows per ASTMID and the duplicates are the same rows you've inserted.

Comment: Use `distinct`: `insert into ... select distinct astmid ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your `ASTMListCustom` table has duplicate rows for the `ASTMID`s on your list. You can fix this by adding a `GROUP BY` to your `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.ASTMListCustom
           ([ASTMID]
           ,[EDMID]
           ,[Distance]
           ,[Selected])    
SELECT     ASTMID
           ,'HWG - VT'
           ,1
           ,1
FROM   dbo.ASTMListCustom
WHERE ASTMID IN ( 15, ... )
GROUP BY ASTMID
```

Comment: Thanks dasblinkenlight!